# Учебники по OpenGL в Windows.

Tags: c++, opengl

Подскажите пожалуйста учебники или самоучители по программированию на С++ OpenGL в Windows (в Visual Studio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. OpenGL Суперкнига Автор Липчак
2. Интерактивная компьютерная графика на базе OpenGL Автор Эйнджел
3. OpenGL Руководство по программированию Авторы Девис, Нейдер, Шрайнер
4. OpenGL Трехмерная графика и язык программирования шейдеров Автор Рост
5. Уроки NeHe  http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/index.html
6. OpenGL Extensions Viewer качаем отсюда http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/
7. Новости смотрим здесь http://www.opengl.org/
8. Красная книга http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/
9. Синяя книга http://www.opengl.org/documentation/blue_book/

Comment: Суперкнигу уважаю. Сам от корки до корки прочитал. Всё понятно расписано. 4-й пункт тоже нужная штука.